# MinGW-w64 Vs TDM-GCC Vs othes minor distros e.g . MinGW Distro - nuwen.net

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, tdm-mingw

Who is more accustomed can tell me:

1. How many flavors has MinGW?
2. actually what are the differences among the various flavors of MinGW? and why prefer one vs another?

I google a bit and till now i found :

MinGW     (http://www.mingw.org/MinGW-w64 )

MinGW-64  (http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)

TDM-GCC   (://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/)

Sezero personal build ([://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/)

Ruben personal build  ([//sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/)

nuwen.net  (://nuwen.net/mingw.html )

Cheers

H.G.K.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980774/what-is-the-difference-between-orwells-mingw-and-tdm-dev-c-versions