# Differences between Mingw-w64 and TDM-GCC for a simple GDI project

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, mingw-w64, tdm-mingw

I need to build a simple non-commercial tool (dealing with Windows GDI API) on Win64 for Win64  (no cross compilation). MinGW seems the best option for me.
I have already used the 32 bit version in the past, as for 64-bit, can you tell me the main differences between the following builds?:

1. [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net)
2. [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net)

Besides the classic MinGW32 used a straightforward tool, `mingw-get.exe`, to customise the setup and keep up with the updating cycle. Which is the equivalent now?

Comment: Use the mingw-builds implementation of Mingw-w64. They maintain the package and have improved on the original Mingw-w64. Also check out MSYS2 -- it is sweet! You can use their pacman package manager to download and install the ming32 and mingw64 bit builds, along with a bunch of other software like Qt, git, subversion, etc...

Comment: There are even more toolchains (e.g. clang) that can be used as alternative to MSVC++ ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I reworded narrowing significantly the scope of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've posted a short overview of MinGW / MinGW-w64 / TDM-GCC here: [What is the difference between Orwell's MinGW and TDM Dev-C++ versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980774/what-is-the-difference-between-orwells-mingw-and-tdm-dev-c-versions/22185860)

> Which is the equivalent now?

[It seems](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/26636994/), there's no MinGW-W64 version of mingw-get; not sure if this is still valid. However, MinGW-w64 contains a nice installer.

Btw. MinGW-w64 is not just a *"64 Bit port of MinGW"* - [it's more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64).

Comment: Sorry but in your previous post you say "My recommendation: Use the 3rd alternative: MinGW-w64 instead", but don't say why you suggest this. What is in MinGW-w64 not in TDM-GCC and vice versa?

Comment: TDM uses the MinGW(-w64) runtime apis and is more a combination of gcc tools and mingw(-w64). MinGW-W64 as a good documentation and is very active. It also contributes lots of nice other stuff like pthread port for windows. The chance that a project supports MingGW is higher than TDM i think.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late answer, but I have this same question and I was looking for by many hours and this is what I found...

I think that this [link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit) can to expand our view of the differences that include every distro, although the recommendation summary is based in their UI framework library (Qt 5)...

http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit

Comment: I'd suggest that you don't simply paste links (as links can break in the future), but expand on your answer here and have the links as a backup.