# cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, cgo

#### Error is resolved on Command Prompt

Previously, I was receiving this error on Command Prompt, but was resolved by [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867163/3405291):

> cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

#### How to resolve error for VS Code debugger

Now, VS Code debugger is throwing the same error:

> # runtime/cgo
>
> cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
>
> exit status 2
>
> Process exiting with code: 1

[image: Error screenshot]

So far I tried:

- Restarting VS Code
- Adding `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\` to the top of the VS Code terminal path:

```
set PATH=C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\;%PATH%
```

[image: Adding to path]

- Modifying `.vscode\launch.json` like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [],
    "environment": [{"name": "Path", "value":  "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin;${env:Path};"}],
}
```

[image: Screenshot: launch.json]

What else can  I try?

Comment: [Please don't paste images of code or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: @Flimzy Code and error messages are added too =)

Comment: Not sure about setting PATH inside VS Terminal, might want to set it globally in your System Settings, and reboot.

Comment: @rustyx I have done so :) That's how I resolved the error for Command Prompt. But VS Code debugger is throwing the same error! Looks like it has no effect on VS Code debugger.

Comment: What I mean is set it outside VS Code, in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment... Also might want to test compiling a simple C program with `gcc -m64`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by @rustyx a computer reboot resolved the problem. I don't exactly know why a reboot is needed for VS Code debugger to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a reboot is required to update your PATH variables, so after installing gcc you need to restart for VS Code to recognize the gcc path.