# Compile C in windows: TDM vs MinGW

Tags: c, windows, mingw, tdm-mingw

I was reading about different C compilers and want to figure out the proper way to compile C programs in windows. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980774/what-is-the-difference-between-orwells-mingw-and-tdm-dev-c-versions) link on the go and then I started reading about TDM and minGW compilers. What information i gained from the reading is:

> 1. TDM-GCC is a compiler suite for Windows.
> 2. It can create 32-bit OR 64-bit binaries, for any version of Windows since Windows 98.

About minGW

> Mingw-w64 was started in order to port an ObjectiveC application to
>   64bit Windows in 2005. The only compiler targeting Windows that
>   supported ObjectiveC was the GCC compiler from MinGW.

AS short, What i understood is both are C compilers for windows and both are independent. 
But when I install TDM-gcc there is a prompt asking to select minGW or minGW-w64. So TDM is depended on minGW? Both are not independent compilers? I am confused by reading different things from different places. Please explain their relevance. The above link was not sufficient for me to understand completely.

Comment: [TDM](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net) doesn't look to have been updated for a couple of years. So if you want a "new" compiler you should probably go with MinGW directly anyway.

Comment: I want to understand what these things are really are and how they are related

Comment: From [about](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/about): "It [TDM-GCC] combines the most recent stable release of the GCC toolset, a few patches for Windows-friendliness, and the free and open-source MinGW or MinGW-w64 runtime APIs to create an open-source alternative to Microsoft's compiler and platform SDK."

Comment: If you're interested in C language, not C++, give a try to PellesC http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/, free also for professional use.